# jQuery Ajax post to php not catching variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

What am i doing wrong. PHP doesn't seem to catch `title` and `wrapper` from $.ajax. Does the code look correct. The success message i get indicate an error that title is not found.

jQuery main.html

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: 'title=test&wrapper=testing',
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   } 
});
```

PHP process.php

```
<?php 
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$wrapper = $_REQUEST['wrapper'];
...
?>
```

Comment: add print_r($_REQUEST) to see what's comming in. Also try replacing it with $_POST

Comment: I've just checked your js code and it works. 
my process.php: 
`<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['title']; 
$b = $_REQUEST['wrapper']; 
echo "title: $a, wrapper: $b"; 
?>
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

The data parameter is better to be a Key/Value pairs object, it's cleaner and easier to debug :)

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: {
     title: 'test',
     wrapper: 'testing'
     },
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   } 
});
```

Comment: Accoding to documentation ` It is converted to a query string, if not already a string`

Comment: true, I missed that. + for you :)

Comment: It was a comma syntax error that i overlooked. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery was this for? It does not seem to work with 1.7.2. The $_REQUEST variable ends up empty.

Answer (score -1):

Thats a good solution.but if I try to send data through a form in a webservice.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: {
     title: $('#title').val,
     name: $('#name').val
     },
   success: function(data){
     alert(data );
   } 
});
```

Here title and name are forms element in client side.but i am not able to get post value in json based webservice file say process.php